# How to delete boundary lines of split shapefile tiles with SQL of Virtual Layer

Tags: qgis, sql

I have the split shapefiles like same size tiles.
I want to show these merged on QGIS.

So, I tried to use Virtual Layer like following image.
[image]

And, I wrote following SQL:

```
select * from north
UNION
select * from central
UNION
select * from west
```

But, the boundary line of shapefile shown.
I want this,

[image]

In this case, how do I write SQL?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you have to UNION the geometry with ST_UNION and grouping the geometrys by one or more unique fields. The statement should be like this one (where name is the unique field/identifier in the example below):

```
SELECT ST_UNION(geometry), name FROM 
(
SELECT central.geometry, name FROM central 
UNION SELECT north.geometry, name FROM north 
UNION SELECT west.geometry, name FROM west
) 
GROUP BY name
```

Answer (score 0):

1) If the structure of your input data is the same, you were very close:

`select * from "north" UNION ALL select * from "central" UNION ALL select * from "west"`

2) Now you need to connect sub-polygons that only touch the cut lines with an operator where with explicit identifiers, for example:

`update union_table set geometry=ST_UNION(geometry) where union_table.ID =1 or union_table.ID =2...`